# How can I make this SQL query work in LINQ lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

```
select * 
from table1 
where Deptno not in (select distinct Deptno from table2)
```

I am not sure how to convert this SQL into a lambda expression. Kindly help me.

Comment: Hard to provide you with the correct LINQ query without seeing your actual Entities and their relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
from x in table1
where !(from y in table2 select y.Deptno).Distinct().Contains(x.Deptno)
select x
```

Answer (score -1):

As we don't know much details about your db..

you could try linqer: http://www.sqltolinq.com/downloads

there you can connect to your db and convert your query